# Are there any two variable function which are invertible?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was working on a computer problem and figured out a function which takes two input $$f(x,y)=L$$ but also yields back original input for $$f^-(L)=x,y$$ also for every unique pair of x,y there be unique L also x,y is not same as y,x

I am a novice in mathematics can anyone tell do such functions exist?

Comment: It depends on your range and domain.

Comment: Use a cardinality argument.

Comment: @copper.hat It would be better if range and domain fall within same set
x,y will be necessarily whole numbers

Comment: Since the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2 $ is the same then yes, there are lots of invertible functions of the form you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, such functions exists. They are called [bijections](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) and it's known that there's such functions between the plane and the real line.

Comment: @jjagmath can you give one example?

Comment: I can give you the idea, the details are nasty. $(.123, .456) \mapsto .142536$

Comment: @jjagmath prima facie it seems to suffice let see weather it works or not